# Ogre3D and CEGUI cannot locate resource group "schemes" in TaharezLook.scheme

Tags: resources, ogre3d, cegui

Perhaps someone can find an answer to my problem. I've tried to follow the basic tutorial #7 from the OGre3D wiki months ago but gave up because I could not solve this problem. I picked it up again and I can't find any kind of help anywhere. I've used search engines many, many, many times with exact phrases among other things.

```
#ifndef __BasicTutorial7_h_
#define __BasicTutorial7_h_

#include "BaseApplication.h"
#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
#include "../res/resource.h"
#endif



#include <CEGUI/cegui/include/CEGUI.h>
#include <CEGUI/cegui/include/RendererModules/Ogre/CEGUIOgreRenderer.h>

class BasicTutorial7 : public BaseApplication
{
public:
    BasicTutorial7(void);
    virtual ~BasicTutorial7(void);

protected:
    CEGUI::OgreRenderer* mRenderer;

    virtual void createScene(void);

    virtual void createFrameListener(void);

    // Ogre::FrameListener
    virtual bool frameRenderingQueued(const Ogre::FrameEvent& evt);

    // OIS::KeyListener
    virtual bool keyPressed( const OIS::KeyEvent &arg );
    virtual bool keyReleased( const OIS::KeyEvent &arg );
    // OIS::MouseListener
    virtual bool mouseMoved( const OIS::MouseEvent &arg );
    virtual bool mousePressed( const OIS::MouseEvent &arg, OIS::MouseButtonID id );
    virtual bool mouseReleased( const OIS::MouseEvent &arg, OIS::MouseButtonID id );

    bool quit(const CEGUI::EventArgs &e);
};

#endif // #ifndef __BasicTutorial7_h_


    #include "BasicTutorial7.h"
CEGUI::MouseButton convertButton(OIS::MouseButtonID buttonID)
{
    switch (buttonID)
    {
    case OIS::MB_Left:
        return CEGUI::LeftButton;

    case OIS::MB_Right:
        return CEGUI::RightButton;

    case OIS::MB_Middle:
        return CEGUI::MiddleButton;

    default:
        return CEGUI::LeftButton;
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BasicTutorial7::BasicTutorial7(void)
{
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BasicTutorial7::~BasicTutorial7(void)
{
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void BasicTutorial7::createScene(void)
{
mRenderer = &CEGUI::OgreRenderer::bootstrapSystem(); //Fire up CEGUI.
/* The code in this comment block I added after following another small tutorial on cegui's wiki. All it gave me was a access violation exception no matter what path I specified. If you wish to get the error I'm getting, remove this code or keep it commented when you copy & paste into your compiler for testing.
CEGUI::DefaultResourceProvider* rp = static_cast<CEGUI::DefaultResourceProvider*>
(CEGUI::System::getSingleton().getResourceProvider());

rp->setResourceGroupDirectory("schemes", "C:/Users/t/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/OgreSDK/include/CEGUI/datafiles/schemes/");
rp->setResourceGroupDirectory("imagesets", "C:/Users/t/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/OgreSDK/include/CEGUI/datafiles");
rp->setResourceGroupDirectory("fonts", "C:/Users/t/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/OgreSDK/include/CEGUI/datafiles");
rp->setResourceGroupDirectory("layouts", "C:/Users/t/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/OgreSDK/include/CEGUI/datafiles");
rp->setResourceGroupDirectory("looknfeels", "C:/Users/t/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/OgreSDK/include/CEGUI/datafiles");
rp->setResourceGroupDirectory("lua_scripts", "C:/Users/t/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/OgreSDK/include/CEGUI/datafiles");
*/
CEGUI::Imageset::setDefaultResourceGroup("imageset"); //Add the resource groups.
CEGUI::Font::setDefaultResourceGroup("fonts");
CEGUI::WidgetLookManager::setDefaultResourceGroup("looknfeel");
CEGUI::WindowManager::setDefaultResourceGroup("layouts");
CEGUI::Scheme::setDefaultResourceGroup("schemes");


CEGUI::SchemeManager::getSingleton().create("TaharezLook.Scheme"); //Set the skin for CEGUI.
CEGUI::System::getSingleton().setDefaultMouseCursor("TaharezLook", "MouseArrow"); //Set the mouse cursor skin. First parameter specifies the resource group, the second the actual Image.

CEGUI::WindowManager &wmgr = CEGUI::WindowManager::getSingleton();
CEGUI::Window *sheet = wmgr.createWindow("DefaultWindow", "CEGUIDemo/Sheet"); 

CEGUI::Window *quit = wmgr.createWindow("TaharezLook/Button", "CEGUIDemo/QuitButton" );
quit->setText("Quit");
quit->setSize(CEGUI::UVector2(CEGUI::UDim(0.15, 0), CEGUI::UDim(0.05,0) ) );


sheet->addChildWindow(quit);
CEGUI::System::getSingleton().setGUISheet(sheet);
quit->subscribeEvent(CEGUI::PushButton::EventClicked, CEGUI::Event::Subscriber(&BasicTutorial7::quit, this ) );

mSceneMgr->setAmbientLight(Ogre::ColourValue(1, 1, 1));
mSceneMgr->setSkyDome(true, "Examples/CloudySky", 5, 8);
Ogre::Entity* ogreHead = mSceneMgr->createEntity("Head", "ogrehead.mesh");
Ogre::SceneNode* headNode = mSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode(Ogre::Vector3(0, 0, -300));
headNode->attachObject(ogreHead);

Ogre::TexturePtr tex = mRoot->getTextureManager()->createManual(
"RTT",
Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
Ogre::TEX_TYPE_2D,
512,
512,
0,
Ogre::PF_R8G8B8,
Ogre::TU_RENDERTARGET);

Ogre::RenderTexture *rtex = tex->getBuffer()->getRenderTarget();

Ogre::Camera *cam = mSceneMgr->createCamera("RTTCam");
cam->setPosition(100, -100, -400);
cam->lookAt(0, 0, -300);
Ogre::Viewport *v = rtex->addViewport(cam);
v->setOverlaysEnabled(false);
v->setClearEveryFrame(true);
v->setBackgroundColour(Ogre::ColourValue::Black);

CEGUI::Texture &guiTex = mRenderer->createTexture(tex);


    CEGUI::Imageset &imageSet =
      CEGUI::ImagesetManager::getSingleton().create("RTTImageset", guiTex);
    imageSet.defineImage("RTTImage",
                         CEGUI::Point(0.0f, 0.0f),
                         CEGUI::Size(guiTex.getSize().d_width,
                                     guiTex.getSize().d_height),
                         CEGUI::Point(0.0f, 0.0f));

CEGUI::Window *si = CEGUI::WindowManager::getSingleton().createWindow("TaharezLook/StaticImage", "RTTWindow");

si->setSize(CEGUI::UVector2(CEGUI::UDim(0.05f, 0), CEGUI::UDim(0.04f,0) ) );
si->setPosition(CEGUI::UVector2( CEGUI::UDim(0.05f, 0), CEGUI::UDim(0.0f,0) ) );

si->setProperty("Image", CEGUI::PropertyHelper::imageToString(&imageSet.getImage("RTTImage")));

    sheet->addChildWindow(si);

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void BasicTutorial7::createFrameListener(void)
{
    Ogre::LogManager::getSingletonPtr()->logMessage("*** Initializing OIS ***");
    OIS::ParamList pl;
    size_t windowHnd = 0;
    std::ostringstream windowHndStr;

    mWindow->getCustomAttribute("WINDOW", &windowHnd);
    windowHndStr << windowHnd;
    pl.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("WINDOW"), windowHndStr.str()));

    mInputManager = OIS::InputManager::createInputSystem( pl );

    mKeyboard = static_cast<OIS::Keyboard*>(mInputManager->createInputObject( OIS::OISKeyboard, true ));
    mMouse = static_cast<OIS::Mouse*>(mInputManager->createInputObject( OIS::OISMouse, true ));

    mMouse->setEventCallback(this);
    mKeyboard->setEventCallback(this);

    //Set initial mouse clipping size
    windowResized(mWindow);

    //Register as a Window listener
    Ogre::WindowEventUtilities::addWindowEventListener(mWindow, this);

    mRoot->addFrameListener(this);

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool BasicTutorial7::frameRenderingQueued(const Ogre::FrameEvent& evt)
{
   if(mWindow->isClosed())
        return false;

    if(mShutDown)
        return false;

    //Need to capture/update each device
    mKeyboard->capture();
    mMouse->capture();

    //Need to inject timestamps to CEGUI System.
    CEGUI::System::getSingleton().injectTimePulse(evt.timeSinceLastFrame);

    return true;

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool BasicTutorial7::keyPressed( const OIS::KeyEvent &arg )
{

CEGUI::System &sys = CEGUI::System::getSingleton();
sys.injectKeyDown(arg.key);
sys.injectChar(arg.text);

return true;

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool BasicTutorial7::keyReleased( const OIS::KeyEvent &arg )
{
    CEGUI::System::getSingleton().injectKeyUp(arg.key);
                return true;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool BasicTutorial7::mouseMoved( const OIS::MouseEvent &arg )
{
CEGUI::System &sys = CEGUI::System::getSingleton();
sys.injectMouseMove(arg.state.X.rel, arg.state.Y.rel);
// Scroll wheel.
if (arg.state.Z.rel)
    sys.injectMouseWheelChange(arg.state.Z.rel / 120.0f);
return true;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool BasicTutorial7::mousePressed( const OIS::MouseEvent &arg, OIS::MouseButtonID id )
{

CEGUI::System::getSingleton().injectMouseButtonDown(convertButton(id));

return true;


}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool BasicTutorial7::mouseReleased( const OIS::MouseEvent &arg, OIS::MouseButtonID id )
{
    CEGUI::System::getSingleton().injectMouseButtonUp(convertButton(id));
                return true;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool BasicTutorial7::quit(const CEGUI::EventArgs &e)
{
mShutDown = true;
return true;

}


#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include "windows.h"
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
    INT WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR strCmdLine, INT )
#else
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
#endif
    {
        // Create application object
        BasicTutorial7 app;

        try {
            app.go();
        } catch( Ogre::Exception& e ) {
#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
            MessageBox( NULL, e.getFullDescription().c_str(), "An exception has occured!", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR | MB_TASKMODAL);
#else
            std::cerr << "An exception has occured: " <<
                e.getFullDescription().c_str() << std::endl;
#endif
        }

        return 0;
    }

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The tutorial I'm using: [Basic Tutorial 7](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Basic%20Tutorial%207)

When I run Ogre I get this error:

> "OGRE_EXCEPTION(5:ItemIdentityException): Cannot locate a resource
>   group called "schemes" for resource "TaharezLook.scheme" in
>   ResourceGroupManager::openResource at
>   ..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupMananger.cpp( line 688).

Answer (score 0):

In the `resources.cfg` file you have to tell Ogre where to find all required resources for your application. This is done by specifying resource groups and their content.

You failed to tell Ogre where to find the required resources for the CEGUI UI schemes and hence the error you are seeing. The tutorial clearly lists what you need to add to your resources.cfg file in [this section](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Basic+Tutorial+7#Defining_CEGUI_resource_groups).